# Column content wrapper not growing with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have my content wrapper `card__header` grow with flex. To take up the remaining height, so the `card__cta` is always at the bottom, all 3 in line as with the container heights.

My attempt have been to use:

```
.card__content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

This doesn't make the wrapper extend to the full height of the column. I think I need this sorted first before the CTA's can go to the bottom of the columns.

Demo URL:
http://1514531d.ngrok.io/testing123/columndev/

```css
.events-grid__grid {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.events-grid__card {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
}

.card__wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.card__content-wrapper {
  padding: 15px 0 0;
}

.card__header {}
```

```html
<div class="events-grid__grid">
  <div class="card events-grid__card">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__media-wrapper"><img alt="Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special" class="card__media card__media--image" src="http://sheffield.theviperrooms.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/fav-homepage.png"></div>
      <div class="card__content-wrapper">
        <div class="card__header">
          <h3 class="card__heading heading"><a class="heading-link" href="/testing123/event/triple-cooked-dalston-roof-park-august-special/">Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special</a><br></h3>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__cta">
          <a class="card__button" href="#">Read More<span class="button__arrow"></span></a>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card events-grid__card">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__media-wrapper"><img alt="Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special" class="card__media card__media--image" src="http://sheffield.theviperrooms.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/image2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="card__content-wrapper">
        <div class="card__header">
          <h3 class="card__heading heading"><a class="heading-link" href="/testing123/event/triple-cooked-dalston-roof-park-august-special/">Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special</a><br></h3>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__cta">
          <a class="card__button" href="#">Read More<span class="button__arrow"></span></a>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card events-grid__card">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__media-wrapper"><img alt="Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special" class="card__media card__media--image" src="http://sheffield.theviperrooms.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/saturdays-box.png"></div>
      <div class="card__content-wrapper">
        <div class="card__header">
          <h3 class="card__heading heading"><a class="heading-link" href="/testing123/event/triple-cooked-dalston-roof-park-august-special/">Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special</a><br></h3>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__cta">
          <a class="card__button" href="#">Read More<span class="button__arrow"></span></a>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` will get you close but you need a couple more changes:

- `.card__content-wrapper` requires a height, otherwise there is no space for its children to grow into. To do this you need to add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` to `.card__wrapper` and `flex-grow: 1;` to `.card__content-wrapper`
- `.card__header` will need `flex-grow: 1;` to enable it to take up the spare space and push `.card__cta` to the bottom

```css
.events-grid__grid {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.events-grid__card {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
}

.card__wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card__content-wrapper {
  padding: 15px 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card__header {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="events-grid__grid">
  <div class="card events-grid__card">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__media-wrapper"><img alt="Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special" class="card__media card__media--image" src="http://sheffield.theviperrooms.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/fav-homepage.png"></div>
      <div class="card__content-wrapper">
        <div class="card__header">
          <h3 class="card__heading heading"><a class="heading-link" href="/testing123/event/triple-cooked-dalston-roof-park-august-special/">Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special</a><br></h3>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__cta">
          <a class="card__button" href="#">Read More<span class="button__arrow"></span></a>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card events-grid__card">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__media-wrapper"><img alt="Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special" class="card__media card__media--image" src="http://sheffield.theviperrooms.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/image2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="card__content-wrapper">
        <div class="card__header">
          <h3 class="card__heading heading"><a class="heading-link" href="/testing123/event/triple-cooked-dalston-roof-park-august-special/">Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special</a><br></h3>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__cta">
          <a class="card__button" href="#">Read More<span class="button__arrow"></span></a>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card events-grid__card">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__media-wrapper"><img alt="Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special" class="card__media card__media--image" src="http://sheffield.theviperrooms.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/saturdays-box.png"></div>
      <div class="card__content-wrapper">
        <div class="card__header">
          <h3 class="card__heading heading"><a class="heading-link" href="/testing123/event/triple-cooked-dalston-roof-park-august-special/">Triple Cooked: Dalston Roof Park – August Special</a><br></h3>
          <p>A weekly playground for those looking for a more discerning night out. With 2-4-1 drinks all night!</p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__cta">
          <a class="card__button" href="#">Read More<span class="button__arrow"></span></a>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: On my demo URL, try this in inspect element and, if you add the height : 100% to .card__content-wrapper you'll see it extends the height way past the parent .card__wrapper wrapper.

Comment: That'll be because of the height taken up by `.card__media-wrapper`. Give me a sec, I'll come up with another way to get the container to take up the relevant height.

Comment: @wharfdale Please see the updated snippet, by setting the parent container to use flex the height of `.card__header` can be modified to take up the remaining space.

Comment: Spot on perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.